# What is the term $t$, in the expression $E=t^{0}m^{1}c^{2}$?

Tags: special-relativity, time

$E=(t)^{0}(m)^{1}(c)^{2}$.

Here, $m$ = mass of the body.

$c$ = velocity of light.

Is $t$ the time?

Comment: Are you trying to do a dimensional analysis? If not, where does your equation come from?

Comment: its comes by seeing the nature of the result. the exponents are increasing or decreasing by 1 and are all positive.

Comment: i was analysing this famous equation of the 20th century. there is a term $t^{0}$ which results in 1 and does not affect the result in anyway. i'm trying to know the term t.

Comment: you can rename 't' by any of the 25 other letters of the english alphabet.

Comment: How about this equation: $E = t^0 q^0 a^0 (\frac{n}{\sqrt{2-w}})^0 e^{-0\times\text{this term means nothing}} m^1 c^2$.

Comment: It means teeth. $t^0=1$, so $E=m^1c^2$, $t$ could mean anything, and the result is unchanged, so it could mean teeth   also, .

Comment: Rajesh has 1,000 rep on MathSE, so I think the comments should concentrate on working out what is confusing him rather than being facetious.

Comment: @JohnRennie Well, I think vague questions without any background are also not appreciated at Math.SE

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're attempting a dimensional analysis - if this isn't the case ignore the rest of this answer!

If we're trying to guess an equation for the energy we might guess it's some function of mass, the speed of light and time, so we can write a general equation as:

$$ E = t^\alpha m^\beta c^\gamma $$

In dimensional analysis we check to see that the units are consistent, i.e. the units are the same on the left and right sides of the equation. To work out the units of energy we note that energy is force times distance, and force is mass times acceleration and acceleration is distance/time$^2$. So the units of energy are $ML^2T^{-2}$. So if we just write down the units for our equation we get:

$$ ML^2T^{-2} = T^\alpha M^\beta (LT^{-1})^\gamma$$

The exponents of $M$, $L$ and $T$ must match on both sides, so we get three simultaneous equations:

$$ \begin{align}
1 &= \beta \\
2 &= \gamma \\
-2 &= \alpha - \gamma
\end{align} $$

And obviously to satisfy these equations $\alpha$ must be zero. So, if our initial assumption was correct the equation must be:

$$ E = t^0mc^2 $$

and since anything to the power zero is unity this gives us the usual equation for mass-energy equivalence.